# Wrapping HTML tags using Yield with Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, yield

Ruby beginner here.

I am trying to understand yield and how to wrap HTML tags around it and I have been having issues with this code.

```
def tag (tag_name, attributes = nil)
  "<#{tag_name}#{attributes}>#{yield}</#{tag_name}>"
end


style_tag = tag("div", ["class=", "red"]) do
  tag("h1") do
    "Google it"
  end
end
```

my output is :

```
 "<div[\"class=\", \"red\"]><h1>Google it</h1></div>"
```

Thank you

Comment: Your example and output don't match.

Comment: sorry yes, that was a previos example: output is : "<div[\"class=\", \"red\"]><h1>Google it</h1></div>"

Comment: Don't put it in the comment, edit your question so it doesn't get lost.

Comment: Now just add you expected output again so people know what you actually want ;)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with `yield` wich seems to be working fine, but with the attributes parameter. Or rather inserting the parameter into the string.

At the moment you are doing an implicit `Array.to_s` which is where the brackets come from. If you are sure the attributes string is correct, you can do a simple `...#{attributes.join} ...` to join all elements to a proper string (provided the HTML syntax is correct and so on).